# Install TYPO3 8.7.7 with SQL Server on IIS

Tags: sql-server, iis, typo3

I tried to install TYPO3 (8.7.7) on my Webserver (IIS) and I'd like to use my SQL Server instead of MySQL.

I found lots of instructions how to make this (on typo3.org and other websites) but none of these worked for me.

I found out, that I must install two extensions before I start the installation (ADOdb & DBAL). Probably there is my fault.

Can anybody explain step by step how to install these extensions before the TYPO3 installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the following configuration to successfully run TYPO3 on SQL Server on my local windows machine:

```
'DB' => [
    'Connections' => [
        'Default' => [
            'charset' => 'utf-8',
            'dbname' => 't3',
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'password' => 'yourPassword',
            'port' => 1433,
            'user' => 'sa',
        ],
    ],
],
```

It's a bit complicated to set up with the installer as it is not yet "clickable". What you can do is call the install script and when it's asking you to configure the database connection you go to your file system and manually add the config section above (with your connection params of course) in the LocalConfiguration.php file.

Then reload the installer - which should now recognize the configured database connection and let you go to the last step where you can import / create the base tables and data.

Note: At the moment I know of two bigger areas where SQL Server is still a problem with TYPO3 8.7 - that's workspaces and database compare. The last one means that after you have existing data in your SQL Server tables won't let you alter them via the TYPO3 database compare tool - you have to change tables manually if you need to.

Find a gist of the table create statements on https://gist.github.com/psychomieze/9570ea1f578aee7a1fbb68c3240a21c8

Comment: I got some [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot update identity column 'uid' error. Is this because there are some definitions that are not correct in mssql?

Answer (score 0):

With 8.7, Doctrine DBAL has been integrated into the core and ADOdb & DBAL sysexts have been removed as there is no need anymore.

Take a look at the documentation of Doctrine DBAL http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html and it should fit perfectly to the configuration of the DB in `LocalConfiguration.php``

```
'DB' => [
    'Connections' => [
        'Default' => [
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'dbname' => 'typo3',
            'driver' => 'mysqli',
            'host' => 'mysql',
            'password' => 'dev',
            'port' => 3306,
            'user' => 'root',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: 'DB' => [
        'Connections' => [
            'Default' => [
                'user' => 'user',
                'password' => 'password',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'port' => 1433,
                'dbname' => 'typo3',
                'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            ],
        ],
    ],

Comment: with the settings above (in the comment) it isn't working. On step 2 it's showing the error message "Connecting to the database with given settings failed: An exception occoured in driver: MySQL server has gone away". I think the installationroutine is using MySQL instead of MS SQL.

Comment: are you sure there is no other config which overlays yours?

Comment: I'm not sure. In the installation-Step 2 I can only select "Manually configured MySQL TCP/IP connection" or "Manually configured MySQL socket connection" as Databaseconnectionoption. I changed the settings in the following file: <webroot>\typo3conf\LocalConfiguration.php

Comment: The MS SQL server support has been added after 8.7.0 release and is not yet clickable in the installer. It still needs some manual work to set up. Additionally, you may stumble upon the one or the other issue in the backend, and extension support is a bit sparse, too. If you'd count yourself as a starter with TYPO3, you're probably better off using mysql.

Comment: I'm a starter with Typo3 but I would like to learn how to use it with MS SQL (and I won't run MySQL & MS SQL on the same server  or make a new one - I have other applications which already run on MS SQL). In addition I will not use extension at the beginning. @ChristianKuhn Can you explain how to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

Now my Typo3 is working.
I solved my problem a little bit complicated.

I made a test environment and installed Typo3 with MySQL.
Then I copied the database with the "Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant 7.6 for MySQL"
(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54257) to my main environment.

After that I copied all the created folders (typo3conf, typo3temp etc.) to my main environment
and edited the databaseconnection in the LocalConfiguration.php file like Georg Ringer proposed.

When I am installing Typo3 and MSSQL next time I will do it like susi proposed.

Thanks for your help.