# TYPO3 v9 using Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

- PHP 7.3
- pdo_sqlserver_73_nts (installed)
- sqlserver_73_nts (installed)

I'm trying to connect a new install of TYPO3 (v9.5.7) to an instance of SQL Server 2016 running on the same box.

I'm able to establish a connection to the database, using the example from php.net: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php so I'm confident the server *is* accessible.

A similar question has been asked for v8 here [Install TYPO3 8.7.7 with SQL Server on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391368/install-typo3-8-7-7-with-sql-server-on-iis) and it's recommend that you ammend the DB settings in LocalConfiguration when the installer is at stage 2 and essentially "trick" the installer to connect to SQL Server.

I've done that and for some reason it won't connect,

```
'DB' => [
  'Connections' => [
    'Default' => [
      'charset' => 'utf-8',
      'dbname' => 'typo3_db',
      'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'password' => 'password',
      'port' => 1433,
      'user' => 'username',
    ],
  ],
],
```

Is there anything wrong with this connection string? I can't seem to find any other working example.

Thanks as always,

Comment: Just a wild guess but did you try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. 
Try to set the full name of your mssql server: 
'host' => 'COMPUTERNAME/DBNAME',

Comment: Didn't work for me, thank you though. Could you share your LocalConfiguration.php ?